# ArcPy: optional cursor parameter

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I got optional field parameter from **arcpy.GetParameterAsText**.

How can I use **arcpy.da.SearchCursor** no matter if field was given or not?

```
> infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
> field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
> arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc,["SHAPE@", field])
```

The error is  **RuntimeError: Cannot find field ''**

How can I make field_name parameter in cursor optional?

Comment: There are a lot more ArcPy questions asked and answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange than here.

Answer (score 1):

Include a conditional to check whether `field` is getting a value. If it is, then include it in the cursor field list; if not, give a different default.

```
field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# if variable `field` is blank
if field == "" or field is None:
    cursor_fields = ["SHAPE@"]
# otherwise
else:
    cursor_fields = ["SHAPE@", field]

arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, cursor_fields)
```